# Highcharts map drag & move on y axis?

Tags: highcharts

by default, you can zoom in a highcharts map then tap and hold left mouse button and you can move the map on `y axis`, is it possible to do this on `x axis`?

I have tried to use `zoomType:'xy'`, but it does not work

[this is the demo from highchart official](https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/data-class-ranges)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a regression bug which is reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12671

As a workaround use Highmaps v7.2.1 with the below plugin:

```
(function (H) {
  H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'pan', function (proceed) {
    H.each(this.yAxis, function (axis) {
      axis.fixTo = null;
    });
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  });
})(Highcharts);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9ue0v4gz/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, but I need to use bubble chart so I must use Highchart 8.0.0. it there any solution that can fix the is sue for highchart version 8.0.0?

Comment: Hi @jjzjx118_2, The bubble series is also available in version 7.2.1.